# About complex filter java stream

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

I have a question about filter, I wrote two POJO :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
class Person {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private List<Address> address;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
class Address {
    private int id;
    private String street;
    private String city;
}
```

I wrote two collections :

```
   Address address1 = new Address(1, "Main street", "London");
    Address address2 = new Address(2, "Hollywood Boolevard", "Los Angeles");
    Address address3=new Address(3,"Rue de la paix","Paris");

    List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(
            new Person(1, "Tom", Arrays.asList(address1)),
            new Person(2, "Fred", Arrays.asList(address2)),
            new Person(3,"Beth",Arrays.asList(address1,address2)),
            new Person(4,"Marc",Arrays.asList(address1,address3))
    );
```

If I want a list of all adresses it's quite simple with

```
 List<Address> addressList=personList.stream().map(Person::getAddress)
            .flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But here is my problem I want a list of Person where this person live for instance in a street containing "ol" and I don't know how to write this with java stream, in the past I used inner join in sql but now with Java streams how can I do this request ???
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
personList.stream()
          // filter people who has an adress that contains "ol"
          // you could also create a method on Person that check if has this address to make it more readable
          .filter(p -> p.getAddress()
                        .stream()
                        .anyMatch(a -> a.getStreet().contains("ol")))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

UPDATED:
Example with the method on the Person:

```
class Person {
    // ...
    public boolean livesInStreet(String street) {
        return this.address.stream().anyMatch(a -> a.getStreet().contains(street));
    }
}
```

Using the new method:

```
personList.stream()
          .filter(p -> p.livesInStreet("ol"))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: No problem, David, I'm glad to help!